# SQL SUM based on datetime conditions from two columns

Tags: sql, case

please help me with this SQL syntax. Want to get an avr value into Table one based on a unique value per minute from another table.
Best/Peter

**Table 1**

```
Activity, starttime, endtime 
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:00, 2010-01-01 15:05
```

**Table 2**

```
Activity, Minute, Value
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:00, 50
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:01, 10
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:02, 10
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:03, 20
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:04, 10
```

**Outcome wanted**

```
Activity, starttime, endtime, avr Value
Dance, 2010-01-01 15:00, 2010-01-01 15:05, 20
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: tagged with sql, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select avg(t2.value)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.activity = t1.activity and
              t2.minute >= t1.starttime and
              t2.minute < t1.endtime
       ) as avg_value
from table1 t1;
```